# Laravel. Auth. Request

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Начал изучать Laravel. Возникли трудности со стандартной аутентификацией.

```
protected function validator(array $data)
```

Вместо массива при проверки данных возможно ли использовать класс **Request**.

Пробовал банальное изменение **request $data** с добавление **use Illuminate\Http\Request;** это не помогло. Может кто-то может подсказать как это сделать или даст информацию где можно найти что-то похожее?

Comment: Эту строку вы из `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController` взяли?

Comment: Немного, не понял о чём вы

Comment: Вы вырвали кусок строки из файла. Что это за файл?

Comment: Вот сам файл https://github.com/illiashvedov/weather2.0/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php

Comment: Сама аутентификация создавалась artisan make:auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В контроллере `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController` используется трейт `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers`, в котором есть метод:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
  $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
  // ... остальное содержимое.
}
```

То есть `(array $data)` - это и есть `$request->all()`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

// ... остальное содержимое.

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
  use RegistersUsers;

  // ... остальное содержимое.

  protected function validator(array $data)
  {
    return Validator::make($data, [
      'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
      'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
      'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],

      // Дополнительные поля для валидации.
      'surname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
      'gender' => [...],
      'birthday' => [...],
    ]);
  }
```

---

Comment: Благодарю, за ответ. И за такую скорость решения

Comment: Поле `gender` сделайте [списком](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-in-array). Поле `birthday` сделайте [датой](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-date).

Comment: А почему именно **gender** списком, у меня просто в viewes это обычная строка

Comment: Выпадающий список легче валидировать этим [правилом](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-in). Обычно `gender` - это ограниченный по вариантам список. Не так ли?

Comment: Да, а есть какая-то статья по поводу списков? Или же документация

Comment: Я ведь указал https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-in

Comment: Добрый день, хотел ещё узнать а возможно ли валидацию переместить в отдельный класс?

Comment: Можно, перемещайте. А смысл, если это единственный участок кода, где используется валидация при регистрации?

Comment: А как правильно сделать это?

Comment: Валидацию обычно перемещают в [`FormRequest`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation). Задайте лучше полноценный вопрос, объясните зачем это надо: так больше вероятности что кто-то заинтересуется этим вопросом помимо вас.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за информацию

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask